# What's a word or phrase for a prearranged situation seeming otherwise?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's a word or phrase for a situation in which, for example, people in authority pretend to be serious in selecting a new member, whereas they have already decided who to choose?

I googled it but to no avail.

Comment: I upvoted the *rigged* answer. In some cases *foregone conclusion* might also work.

Comment: This sounds very similar to https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/452360/word-to-describe-a-company-that-pretends-to-do-the-right-thing/452361#452361. It's slightly different enough that it might not be a duplicate. (The answer there was "lip service.")

Comment: For this question, an answer could also be "facade" or "act." It's not clear if it's a verb or a noun that's being looked for; something that describes the people themselves, or the situation. (The title of the question implies something different than the body of the question.)

Comment: The word ***pre-arranged*** often features - as in ***pre-arranged result***.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are referring to ***[rigging:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/rigging)***

​

> the act of arranging dishonestly for the result of something, for example an election, to be changed.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

In your specific case you can say that *the context was rigged.*

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a noun, these are possible nouns in descending order of fit:

- sham - The interview was a sham. They'd already decided on someone
  else.
- charade - The interview was a charade.  They'd already decided on
  someone else.
- smoke screen - The interview as a smoke screen. They'd already decided on someone else.
- put-on - The interview was a put-on. They'd already decided on
  someone else.
- production - The interview was a production.  They'd already decided
  on someone else.
- ruse - The interview was a ruse.  They'd already decided on someone
  else.
- pretense - The interview was pretense. They'd already decided on
  someone else.

If you're looking for an adjective, these are a couple of adjectives:

- rigged - The interview was rigged. They'd already decided on someone
  else.
- just for show - The interview was just for show. They'd already
  decided on someone else.